# UICollectionViewCell memory leak when user click image loading all images(150) in slide objective c

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Basically I want to display images in slide which are coming from server. it works for maximum 10 images. And I am displaying them in `UICollectionView` with `Cell` but when I click folder that has 100 +more images it gives me error that memory leak because it loads all images (3Gigabytes+) in one time  when clicked. I tried to call by index it loads clicked image but when i swipe other images are not loading.
I resized all images with Bitmap all works but Image has  too many details when zooming it's impossple to read. Is there any other way to load images one by one when `Cell` calls image?
Here is my `LocalFileDeailViewController.m`

```
(void) initPaging {
CGFloat width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.scrollView.frame.size.height;
CGRect innerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

for (int i = 0; i < self.fileList.count; i++) {
    __block UIImage* Image = nil;
    
    if ([self.ListType  isEqual: @"url"]) {
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: self.fileList[i]]];
        Image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
    } else {
        NSString * filePath = (NSString *) self.fileList[i];
        NSString *imageFullPath = [self.filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];
        BOOL isLoadAble = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imageFullPath];
        if ( isLoadAble ) {
            Image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFullPath];

        } else {
            //TODO 이미지가 없는경우 뭘 표시하나?
            continue;
        }
    }
    
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(i * width, 0, width, height);
    UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:innerFrame] ;
    [imgV setImage:Image];
    [imgV setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imgV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    imgV.tag = VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG;
    
    UIScrollView *psv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [psv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    psv.minimumZoomScale = ZOOM_MIN;
    psv.maximumZoomScale = ZOOM_MAX;
    psv.zoomScale = ZOOM_SCALE;
    psv.contentSize = imgV.bounds.size;
    psv.delegate = self.scrollDelegate;
    psv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    psv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    [psv addSubview:imgV];
    [self.contentView addSubview:psv];
    
    [self.pages addObject:psv];
    
}

self.contentViewWidth.constant = self.fileList.count * width;
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(width * self.index, 0) animated:NO];
```

And `LocalImageGridViewController.m`

```
#define CELL_ID @"LocalFileImageCollectionViewCell"
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LocalFileImageCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString * fileName = (NSString *) self.fileList[indexPath.row];
    [ cell prepareForReuse];
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    [cell setImagePath:self.filePath  imageName:fileName index: indexPath.row];
    if (![cell superview]){
        [_collectionView addSubview:cell];
        
    }
    return cell;

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    
    [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]; NSLog(@"indexpath >>>> %@", indexPath);
//    NSString * fileName = (NSString *) self.fileList[indexPath.row];
    
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    LocalFileImageDetailViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LocalFileImageDetailViewController"];
//    [vc setFileName:fileName];
    [vc setFileName:self.fileName];
    [vc setFilePath:self.filePath];
    [vc setFileList:self.fileList];
    [vc setIndex:indexPath.item];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"vc >>>> %@", vc);
}
```

Comment: You should get the image on demand only, not load all of them on start. You can use a third party (which has optimization (on cell reuse, and also that can resize them), like `SDWebImage`, `KingFisher`, `AFNetworking`, etc.

Comment: @Larme okay how am i supposed to be using that in my case ? I tired like this `[_imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.fileList objectAtIndex:self.index]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageFullPath]];
//                [self.contentView addSubview:imgView];` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should use UICollectionView in LocalFileDeailViewController instead of UIScrollView. Collection view load cells by demand, not on load view controller

Comment: Please explain more about it. Do you mean this line? -> `  UIScrollView *psv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];`